# Jmeter Clear cache after each http request

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to clear the cache after each http request accomplished in a thread group. I have already used the http_cache manager but not successful.

Also tried to add a beanshell sampler with following code but didn't work

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager;

CacheManager clearCache = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cache_manager").getObjectValue();

clearCache.clear();
```

And getting

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager;  CacheManager clear . . . ''
```

Also tried to use the pre/post-processor, but not working. Also added the variable for http header.

Please refer the screenshot attached. 
header-screenshot
[image]
Thread Group 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing cache after each sampler doesn't make any sense because your JMeter script behaviour won't match real browsers behaviour.

The main feature of the HTTP Cache Manager is preventing repeated downloading of the embedded resources like images, scripts, fonts, styles like real browsers do for consecutive HTTP requests. See [HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) article for more details.

If you intend to remove cache between requests - simply don't add the HTTP Cache Manager to your Test Plan.

---

However if you're looking for the way of manually initiating clearing of cache:

- be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy performance is much higher comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- there is `sampler` shorthand in JSR223 Test Elements which stands for HTTPSamplerProxy which in its turn has [`getCacheManager()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getCacheManager--)

So you would need to add a suitable JSR223 Test Element, i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code:

```
sampler.getCacheManager().clear()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I am getting the following error 
`2019/09/18 14:26:16 ERROR - jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 PostProcessor javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method clear() on null object
`

Comment: Then there is no HTTP Cache Manager associated with the Sampler, consider placing it to the correct location according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/). Given you set up your project exactly like at my screenshot you should not be getting any errors. Placing the HTTP Cache Manager as a child of the HTTP Request sampler doesn't make any sense due to the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: I am getting the same error, please check the main thread for attached reference